# Macbook Bluetooth Keyboard some Keys are not working and weird behavior

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth

Since yesterday my XtremeMac bluetooth Apple Keyboard stopped working (partially). I've already had a very weird behaviour in the last month where it switched two keys on the keyboard even though the settings under "Keyboard > Input Sources" were correct. But this time the behaviour is extremely weird - so here is what happens:

- typing normal letters works
- Special Characters (including CMD, Option, Ctrl, Fn, F-keys, backspace, enter and Space) do not work

I've googled a lot already and I'm pretty sure my Keyboard settings under System Preferences are ok:
[image: keyboard settings]

I would like to add a video with the behaviour in action but I can't with StackOverflow :/ But essentially I'm typing "thisworks" and then pressing enter a couple times and this is what's written: Thisworkscmvxcmvx,.cmvxcvxcmvx

The Keyboard Viewer doesn't even show that I've pressed a button that doesn't work... And with another Keyboard it works just fine.

Does anybody have an idea what might have gone wrong and how I can reverse this behaviour?

Comment: The builtin keyboard works as expected?

Comment: If another keyboard works fine, I would suspect the one not working is damaged.

Comment: @nohillside Yes the built-in keyboard as well as another bluetooth keyboard work as expected.

Comment: @TomGewecke isn't it possible that somehow the settings are corrupted for the keyboard?

Comment: Did the keyboard require a separate driver (probably not)? You can also create a new user account on your Mac and check whether the problem occurs there as well.

Comment: It may also be worthwhile to reach out to the vendor directly (https://shop.xtrememac.com/products/multi-device-bluetooth-keyboard-1). Is it actually "Multi Device Bluetooth Keyboard", or is it another one?

Comment: MacOS settings normally apply to all connected keyboards.  Do you have any extra remapping stuff like Karabiner installed?

Comment: @nohillside No, it did not require a separate driver. I've also tested it on another MacBook and same issues there so I would assume that the hardware of the keyboard is damaged :/

Comment: If it is the "Multi Device Bluetooth Keyboard" model, this seems to have special modes you can set depending on the type of computer you use it with.

Comment: @TomGewecke No, I don't have anything like that installed. But as you can see in the other comment, I think the hardware of the keyboard seems to be damaged. But the only thing I've done is to charge the keyboard via USB A over a USB C adapter connected to my MacBook - aaand the odd thing is the tablet I've charged the same way stopped working for a while too this day ^^ I'm not sure if this could be the cause but it seems a bit suspicious.

Comment: @nohillside I think the only special modes are the 3 connection types which I'm not even able to switch because the "Fn" key doesn't work. Please also see the comment above about how it might have happened, maybe this helps a bit with the cause of the problem...